# How do I remove a repository from git gui?

Tags: git

I'm just learning Git and would like to remove my first project from git gui.

Comment: Why not just delete it? `rm -rf the directory`. If you want to just remove "git" from it and not keep the files under source control, remove the `.git` directory at the root of the repository.

Comment: I'm with @vcsjones on this: `git gui` is not a general file-manipulation tool -- rather, it's a front-end to Git. You can delete your project from Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to get rid of the project itself go ahead and delete it if you just want to get rid of the repository and keep the code delete .git folder in the root of your project.

Comment: I have no `.git` folder in the directory but the GUI still tells me there is a repository there. Why?

Comment: .git is a hidden folder in windows maybe thats why.

Answer (score 3):

Under your repository name, click  Settings.

click on delete repository button.

you will get pop-up if you want to permanently delete it then just click on delete button.
Now its done.

Answer (score 0):

First delete the repository under settings.
After that you need to delete the hidden .git folders...
for that use this command in git command line:
`$ rm -rf .git`